# Create a temporary table to hold the data in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a main product table where products are stored. This table has three columns: `Id`, `Name`, `Price`, and sample data like this:

```
 Id  Productname  Price
---- -----------  -----
 1     car1         0
 2     car2         0
```

I want to have a temporary table that is related to table of products :).

I want to register prices for my products in a temporary table through a form and display them in a table.

And after I have recorded the prices of each product in the list of the temporary table and finished, I can apply them to the main table for the same products.

Temporary table columns:

```
productId  Price
---------  -----
```

Is this possible? If so, tell me the best solution so that I can do it?

Comment: Why do you need a table for this instead of holding the data i.e. on client side and then storing it when the user is finished recording the prices?

Comment: A database is just to query data. If you need to apply logic before or after fetching the data, you need to store them in memory (using `List`, `Array`, etc) and display to the user. If then an update is needed, just update that `List` or `Array`.

Comment: @Codingwiz Do you mean to use generic lists?

Comment: @CarlosM.Hernández I want to give a price to some selected products and then register this whole list in the database. In fact, I don't want to give each and every price.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to give a price to some selected products. So then instead of separate temporary table, you can use viewmodel in that case something like below.

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public List<int> ProductIds { get; set; }
    public decimal UpdatedPrice { get; set; }
}
```

```
public void UpdateProducts(ProductViewModel model)
{
    var productIds = model.ProductIds;
    var Uprice = model.UpdatedPrice;

    var listofproducts = context.products
        .Where(p => productIds.Contains(p.Id))
        .ToList();

    foreach (var p in listofproducts)
    {
        p.Price = Uprice;
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```